Python : 2 (or more) conditional formatting for the same Excel range
I have the following code :
Wb.sheets["MySheet"].conditional_format('B2:B15', {'type':'formula',
'criteria':'=(C2:C15="Singular")', 'format':Format1})
        
Wb.sheets["MySheet"].conditional_format('B2:B15', {'type':'formula',
'criteria':'=AND(C2:C15="Plural", B2:B15="Other")', 'format':Format2})

In fact, the first conditional_format does work on the rows where the criteria is respected, but the second conditional_format has no effect (despite the fact that no error message appears).
Thus, is there a way to apply these 2 conditional_format on this same range B2:B15 ?
Thank you for your help.
P.S : I tested the second conditional_format on another range (I randomly picked 'D2:D15'), and it did work. So the issue must be linked to having the same targeted range 'B2:B15'

Does the conditional format work in Excel? For example if those conditional formats are applied manually to a new file in Excel does it give the expected result? I'd guess that it doesn't and that the required formulas should be something like =C2="Singular" and =AND(C2="Plural", B2="Other").

Thank you ! Now, both conditional_format do appear in  my Excel file, not only the first one. Case closed.

Thanks to the comment from @jmcnamara, I used =C2="Singular" and =AND(C2="Plural", B2="Other") and it solved my issue.
